# How to expand loop using macro to declare a variable args function

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this:

```
#define DECLARE_FUNC(n) ???
```

We will get below using a number as input args:

```
DECLARE_FUNC(1)==>int (*)(string)
DECLARE_FUNC(2)==>int (*)(string,string)
DECLARE_FUNC(3)==>int (*)(string,string,string)
....
```

And can also expand the macro using a var like:

```
void caller(void(*func)(),int args){

    using decl = **DECLARE_FUNC(args);**//!!!I want expanding the macro using a variable.!!
    ...
    ...
}
```

It is simple to get the correct results using a number as input, but I am confused when a var is passed in.

Comment: You can't expand a macro using the value of a runtime variable. That's a nonstarter.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It would help if you could explain your underlying goal because this smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: While it's possible to fake loops in macros, it seems pretty likely that a variadic template would serve your use case better than a macro.

Comment: Macros are holdover from C, there is almost always a better solution than a macro.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `const std::vector<std::string>&`.